# Multicasting for WDS

Tags: firewall, router, multicast, wds, windows-7

I want to install a Windows 7 image on 40-something computers without touching 'em

I have a WDS server, an image captured, and an answer file setup.  I go to create a multicast transmission out of the image, but I can't see it on my client computer.

I think it may be because my router doesn't support PIM (it's an IPCop firewall) but I'm not sure it would need to if I'm just multicasting to client computers within the network that the router.

So my question: if I want to do this, will I need to have a router/firewall that supports multicasting in order to multicast to client computers on my internal network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all parts of the network between the server and the client will need to support multicast. The WDS server needs to be configured, DHCP needs to support multicast addresses and the router/switch needs to understand it.

You may find the links [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardwu/archive/2010/07/21/useful-document-reference-for-wds-multicast.aspx) to be helpful.

Comment: so even though the multicasting never goes outside of the network, my router still has to support multicasting? Wouldn't the switches handle all of that?

Comment: Well when I say router/switch, I mean any/all devices that you need the packets to traverse, regardless of whether they are routers, switches or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you all your computers are behind the router and on the same subnet, thus the router is not required to route any packets, then the router should not have to support multicast.

Does your PC successfully boot into WDS and you simply don't see the options in the boot menu ?

Multicast, only starts working after choosing this option, so if u don't get this far it its another issue.